# Total duration of adverse events with overlapping in R

Tags: date, overlapping

I am trying to find the total duration of adverse events with overlapping per patient in R.
I have a dataset with many rows per patient with the start and end date of adverse events in each row. If I sort the dataset with the start date, the dates of adverse events are overlapping not only with the previous row. How can I find the  real  total duration of the adverse events per patient in R without the days of the overlapping?
The test dataset that I created is:

PatID AE_start       AE_stop
1    2020-01-01       2020-02-01
1    2020-01-01       2020-02-01
1    2020-03-01       2020-03-05
1    2020-03-01       2020-03-05
1    2020-04-06       2020-04-07
2    2020-01-31       2020-03-31
2    2020-01-31       2020-07-31
3    2020-02-01       2020-06-01
3    2020-02-01       2020-02-06
3    2020-02-01       2020-02-04
3    2020-02-02       2020-02-04
3    2020-03-01       2020-07-03
3    2020-04-01       2020-06-03
4    2023-01-01       2023-04-01
4    2023-01-01       2023-02-01
4    2023-02-03       2023-04-01
5    2020-02-01       2020-05-01
5    2020-02-01       2020-02-03
5    2020-02-03       2020-02-06
5    2020-03-01       2020-03-02
5    2020-04-06       2020-05-01
5    2020-04-06       2020-05-01

Thank you in advance

I tried some codes but with no success:
i.e. the first that I tried is the following but it doesn't work correctly for patid=3 due to the fact that there is AE_stop=2020-06-03 after 2020-07-03 and the code looks only the previous row but for me I would like to look all the previous rows. (AE_data is the dataset above)

sorted_data <- AE_data[order(AE_data$PatID, AE_data$AE_start,AE_data$AE_stop), ]

## base duration

sorted_data$duration <- difftime(sorted_data$AE_stop, sorted_data$AE_start, units="days")#+1

## calculate overlap

sorted_data$overlap <- 0

## test for the first three rows

sorted_data$PatID[3]==sorted_data$PatID[3-1]
min(sorted_data$AE_stop[3],sorted_data$AE_stop[2-1]) - sorted_data$AE_start[3]#+1

for(i in 2:nrow(sorted_data)){
samepat <- sorted_data$PatID[i]==sorted_data$PatID[i-1] # flag for same patient

if ( (sorted_data$AE_start[i]<=sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]) & (sorted_data$AE_stop[i]>=sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1]) )   { curovl<-sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1] - sorted_data$AE_start[i-1] }
if ( (sorted_data$AE_start[i]>=sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]) & (sorted_data$AE_stop[i]<=sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1])) { curovl <- sorted_data$AE_stop[i] - sorted_data$AE_start[i] }
if ( (( (sorted_data$AE_start[i]<=sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]) & (sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]<=sorted_data$AE_stop[i]))) & (sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1]>sorted_data$AE_stop[i])) { curovl <- sorted_data$AE_stop[i] - sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]}
if ( ( (sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]<=sorted_data$AE_start[i]) & (sorted_data$AE_start[i]<=sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1])) & (sorted_data$AE_stop[i]>sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1]) ) { curovl <- sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1] - sorted_data$AE_start[i]}
if ( (sorted_data$AE_start[i-1]>sorted_data$AE_stop[i]) | (sorted_data$AE_start[i]>sorted_data$AE_stop[i-1])) { curovl <- 0}

if(curovl>0 & samepat) sorted_data$overlap[i] <- curovl
}

## aggregate duration and overlap

res <- aggregate(duration ~ PatID, data=sorted_data, sum)
res$overlap <- aggregate(overlap ~ PatID, data=sorted_data, sum)[,2] # aggregate overlap

## calculate corrected value

res$corrected <- res$duration - res$overlap # correct